# Oscillating processing speed in a python script using pysam.TabixFile to annotate reads

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, bioinformatics, samtools

### The initial question

I'm writing a bioinformatics script in python (3.5) that parses a large (sorted and indexed) [bam](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf) file representing sequencing reads aligned on a genome, associates genomic information ("annotations") to these reads, and counts the types of annotations encountered. I'm measuring the speed at which my script processes aligned reads (over batches of 1000 reads), and I obtain the following speed variations:

[image: read processing speed using tabix]

**What could explain this pattern?**

My intuition would make me bet on some data structure that progressively gets slower as it gets denser, but which is expanded from time to time.

It doesn't seem that memory usage is significant, though (after almost 2 hours running, my script still uses only 0.1% of the memory of my computer, according to `htop`).

**How my code works** (see at the end for the actual code)

I'm using the `pysam` module to do the bam file parsing. The [AlignmentFile.fetch](http://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pysam.AlignmentFile.fetch) method gives me an iterator providing information about successive aligned reads in the form of [AlignedSegment](http://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pysam.AlignedSegment) objects.

I associate annotations to the reads based on their alignment coordinates and an annotation file in [gtf](http://www.ensembl.org/info/website/upload/gff.html) format (compressed with bgzip and indexed with [tabix](http://www.htslib.org/doc/tabix.html)). I use the [TabixFile.fetch](http://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pysam.TabixFile.fetch) method (still from `pysam`) to get these annotations, I filter them and yield a summary of them in the form of a `frozenset` of strings (`process_annotations`, not shown below, returns such a `frozenset`), in a generator function that internally loops over the AlignedSegment iterator.

I feed the generated frozensets to a `Counter` object. Could the counter be responsible for the observed speed behaviour ?

**How can I find out how to avoid these regular slowing?**

---

### Additional tests

Following suggestions in the comments, I profiled my whole analysis using `cProfile` and found that the most running time was spent while accessing annotation data (`pysam/ctabix.pyx:579(__cnext__)`, see the call graph later), which, if I understand correctly is some Cython code interfacing with the samtools C libraries. It seemed the cause for the observed slowing would be difficult to understand.

In an attempt to speed up my script, I tried another solution based on the `pybedtools` python interface with bedtools, which can also retrieve annotations from gtf files (https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/index.html).

#### Speed

The speed improvement is quite important. Here are the actual command and timing results (the two were actually run in parallel):

```sh
$ time python3 -m cProfile -o tests/total_pybedtools.prof ~/src/bioinfo_utils/small_RNA_seq_annotate.py -b results/bowtie2/mapped_C_elegans/WT_1_21-26_on_C_elegans_sorted.bam -g annotations/all_annotations.gtf -a "pybedtools" -l total_pybedtools.log > total_pybedtools.out

real    5m48.474s
user    5m48.204s
sys     0m1.336s

$ time python3 -m cProfile -o tests/total_tabix.prof ~/src/bioinfo_utils/small_RNA_seq_annotate.py -b results/bowtie2/mapped_C_elegans/WT_1_21-26_on_C_elegans_sorted.bam -g annotations/all_annotations.gtf.gz -a "tabix" -l total_tabix.log > total_tabix.out

real    195m40.990s
user    194m54.356s
sys     0m47.696s
```

(To be noted: the annotation results are slightly different between the two approached. Maybe I should check how I handle coordinates.)

The speed profile doesn't have the previously observed long-period drops:

[image: read processing speed using pybedtools]

My speed problem is solved but **I'm still interested in hindsight as to why the tabix-based approach has these speed drops**. I added the "bioinformatics" and "samtools" tag for this reason.

#### Call graphs

For the record, I generated call graphs using gprof2dot on the profiling results:

```sh
$ gprof2dot -f pstats tests/total_pybedtools.prof \
    | dot -Tpng -o tests/total_pybedtools_callgraph.png
$ gprof2dot -f pstats tests/total_tabix.prof \
    | dot -Tpng -o tests/total_tabix_callgraph.png
```

Here is the call graph for the tabix-based approach:

[image: Call graph when using tabix]

For the pybedtools-based approach:

[image: Call graph when using pybedtools]

#### The code

Here is the main part of my current code:

```
@contextmanager
def annotation_context(annot_file, getter_type):
    """Yields a function to get annotations for an AlignedSegment."""
    if getter_type == "tabix":
        gtf_parser = pysam.ctabix.asGTF()
        gtf_file = pysam.TabixFile(annot_file, mode="r")
        fetch_annotations = gtf_file.fetch
        def get_annotations(ali):
            """Generates an annotation getter for *ali*."""
            return fetch_annotations(*ALI2POS_INFO(ali), parser=gtf_parser)
    elif getter_type == "pybedtools":
        gtf_file = open(annot_file, "r")
        # Does not work because somehow gets "consumed" after first usage
        #fetch_annotations = BedTool(gtf_file).all_hits
        # Much too slow
        #fetch_annotations = BedTool(gtf_file.readlines()).all_hits
        # https://daler.github.io/pybedtools/topical-low-level-ops.html
        fetch_annotations = BedTool(gtf_file).as_intervalfile().all_hits
        def get_annotations(ali):
            """Generates an annotation list for *ali*."""
            return fetch_annotations(Interval(*ALI2POS_INFO(ali)))
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("%s not available" % getter_type)
    yield get_annotations
    gtf_file.close()

def main():
    """Main function of the program."""
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description=__doc__,
        formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter)
    parser.add_argument(
        "-b", "--bamfile",
        required=True,
        help="Sorted and indexed bam file containing the mapped reads."
        "A given read is expected to be aligned at only one location.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-g", "--gtf",
        required=True,
        help="A sorted, bgzip-compressed gtf file."
        "A corresponding .tbi tabix index should exist.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-a", "--annotation_getter",
        choices=["tabix", "pybedtools"],
        default="tabix",
        help="Method to use to access annotations from the gtf file.")
    parser.add_argument(
        "-l", "--logfile",
        help="File in which to write logs.")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if not args.logfile:
        logfilename = "%s.log" % args.annotation_getter
    else:
        logfilename = args.logfile
    logging.basicConfig(
        filename=logfilename,
        level=logging.DEBUG)
    INFO = logging.info
    DEBUG = logging.debug
    WARNING = logging.warning
    process_annotations = make_annotation_processor(args.annotation_getter)
    with annotation_context(args.gtf, args.annotation_getter) as get_annotations:
        def generate_annotations(bamfile):
            """Generates annotations for the alignments in *bamfile*."""
            last_t = perf_counter()
            for i, ali in enumerate(bamfile.fetch(), start=1):
                if not i % 1000:
                    now = perf_counter()
                    INFO("%d alignments processed (%.0f alignments / s)" % (
                        i,
                        1000.0 / (now - last_t)))
                    #if not i % 50000:
                    #    gc.collect()
                    last_t = perf_counter()
                yield process_annotations(get_annotations(ali), ali)
        with pysam.AlignmentFile(args.bamfile, "rb") as bamfile:
            annot_stats = Counter(generate_annotations(bamfile))
            print(*reversed(annot_stats.most_common()), sep="\n")
    return 0
```

(I used a contextmanager and other higher-order functions (`make_annotation_processor` and functions this one calls) to make it easier to have various annotation retrieving approaches in the same script.)

Comment: Without further analysis, I would think of a garbage collector cleaning unused memory at regular intervals

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try to run `gc.collect()` more frequently than the observed oscillation period and see if the speed pattern changes.

Comment: Appending to a list  is *amortized* `O(1)`. You still have to pay. Maybe the spikes are where data structures are copied and padded so that they can grow some more (which will also involve garbage collection). The crucial action seems to take place in code contained in modules that are not shown, so it is just guess work. If you know how much space is needed, perhaps the underlying code can be modified so that it preallocates the needed space (easy to do with a list, I'm not sure how with a dictionary).

Comment: I suggest you profile your script and see where it's spending most of its time. See [_How can you profile a Python script?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script) This will likely give you a significant clue as to what is going on.

Comment: Running `gc.collect()` every 50000 reads (more frequently than the observed oscillation period, which is around a few 100000 reads) doesn't change the speed profile.

Comment: @martineau I added some profiling results. I'm not sure how to interpret it.

Comment: Well, the items at the top of the list are those that are taking most of the execution time. Some you can do nothing about, like the internal implementation of `exec`, except by not using it (which may not be feasible). The others are things you may be able to do something about, either by changing your algorithm, or by finding a third-party extension (typically written in C) that can provide the functionality your need but runs faster than the built-ins you're currently using. The profiler is also good for development because you quickly see the effect of any changes you make as you go along.